# POST request (GWT : Requestbuilder). Wrong content type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of application/xml

Tags: xml, rest, gwt, jax-rs, content-type

I want to call my REST service on the client side (GWT) using RequestBuilder. I need to serialize a complex type (Connexion), i chose Piriti. The serialization seems to work fine.
Then i attach the string representation of my complex object to the body's request and send the POST request.

But i have the following error :

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.ald.projet.property.Connexion of content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I use RESTeasy on the server-side, it seems that it doesn't receive the correct content type.

I checked with firebug, the content type of my request is application/xml ...not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

> ```
> Request headers
>  Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
>  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
>  Accept: application/xml
>  Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>  Connection: keep-alive
>  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Front_End.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
>  Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
>  Content-Length: 109
>  Pragma: no-cache
>  Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Response headers
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>   Server  Jetty(6.1.x)
> ```

POST content

```
<connexion>
  <login>azerty</login>
  <password>azerty</password>
</connexion>
```

**Client-side**

```java
    Connexion connexion = new Connexion("azerty", "azerty");

    String url ="proxy.jsp?url=" + URL.encode("http://localhost:8080/rest/service/connexion");
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);

    builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    builder.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml"); 

    //serialization with Piriti     
    String xml = Connexion.WRITER.toXml(connexion);
    builder.setRequestData(xml);

    builder.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            GWT.log(response.getText());
            System.out.println(response.getText().trim());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        }
    });

    try{
        builder.send();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Rest Service (server side)**

```java
@POST
@Path("/connexion")
//@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response connexion(Connexion connexion){
    String status = connexionDAO.isValidConnection(connexion);
    
    return Response.ok(status).build();
    
}
```

**Connexion.java** client side

```java
public class Connexion {

interface ConnexionReader extends XmlReader<Connexion> {}
public static final ConnexionReader XML = GWT.create(ConnexionReader.class);


public interface ConnexionWriter extends XmlWriter<Connexion> {}
public static final ConnexionWriter WRITER = GWT.create(ConnexionWriter.class);


private String login;
private String password;

public Connexion(){
    
}


public Connexion(String login, String password) {
    super();
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

**Connexion.java** server side

```java
@Embeddable
@XmlRootElement(name = "connexion")
public class Connexion {

private String login;
private String password;

public Connexion(){
    
}

public Connexion(String login, String password) {
    super();
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

@XmlElement
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

@XmlElement
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

what is happening and what can i do in order to make it work ?

Thx in advance

Comment: i still don't have the answer, it gives me headach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact my proxy was modifying the content of my request.

I deployed my GWT application on Jetty (back-end) and that solved it, it lasts only one server so i don't have SOP issue.
No need to use some proxy anymore, but every time i change something in the client side i have to re deploy it and it's a loss of time.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment @Consumes("application/xml") to process as XML instead of default application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: When i uncomment @Consumes, it tells : "Cannot consume content-type". I think the error is caused by my proxy (used to avoid Same Origin Policy). How could i avoid SOP without proxy ?